# Release a pointer to a Direct2D Factory COM object in C [d2d1.h]

Tags: c, pointers, winapi, com, direct2d

### The problem

I am following a [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-direct2d-program) from the Microsoft Documentation and the examples there are given in C++. I could've just used the default samples in C++, but I wanted to further understand how the API works so I decided to rewrite the default C++ sample in C.

The problem I encountered is that I can easily call `D2D1CreateFactory` and create an `ID2D1Factory`, though when I was previously reading the documentation, it was stated that you have to always release the COM object after you've used it and don't need it anymore. The fact is that in C++ there's an inherited method `Release` from `IUnknown`. In C though there's no even a `lpVtbl`, which as far as I understand is usually needed for that purpose. The `ID2D1Factory` is just provided as a `typedef` and is an *incomplete type*.

And now I'm stuck, because I don't know how to release pointer. I've spent a couple of hours searching for ways to do that in C.
Is it even possible?

The header file: `d2d1.h`

### The Code

Window Procedure *simplified*:

```
switch (uMessage)
{
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HRESULT hResult = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &IID_ID2D1Factory, NULL, &pFactory);
        if (FAILED(hResult))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
...
}
```

Obviously `pFactory` is of an `ID2D1Factory*` type in global scope. It is *zero-initialized* by default (if that helps).

Comment: It seems the C definitions were removed from the SDK from release 14393. If you target your project to use release 10586 it should work. Reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b557dbb1-79d5-4a2d-b8fc-5dc07ab0637d/is-plain-c-actually-supported-for-direct2d?forum=windowssdk

Comment: Thanks @JonathanPotter! TBH wasn't expecting Microsoft the remove the definitions. Is there a way to release the pointer now or I just have to target an older SDK / Code my own COM object? Either way you can write your answer so that I can mark it as the solution! ^_^

Comment: You should be able to release the pointer by casting it to an `IUnknown*` and call the Release method from there. But without the definitions you won't be able to do much else with the factory, so it seems a bit pointless.

Comment: Casting isn't a safe option. Reference counts in COM are strictly per interface. If you have a pointer to an `ID2D1Factory` interface, you're going to have to call through that interface's `Release` implementation.

Comment: As for the code in question, the final argument is wrong. It needs to be the address of a pointer variable, yet the code is passing the pointer variable itself.

Comment: @IInspectable In the real code I have a factory wrapped into a struct and I'm actually passing the factory pointer address. Thanks for pointing it out though!

Comment: These are old headers that don't use powerful .idl (although idl exists from the beginning of time...). One solution is to redeclare the interface in a custom.idl and run "midl custom.idl" so the midl tool will create everything for you, like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/pu9h3BTU

Comment: That was probably removed because direct2d interfaces in general are not C-friendly, and can't be used as-is with the way midl works. Factory interface is fine for that, but some others are not. Casting to IUnknown* is obviously fine.

Comment: @bun Direct2D interfaces are in no way special. There's *nothing* about them that would make them *"not C-friendly"*. As with any other COM interface, the only [language-level requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model) are *"that code is generated in a language that can create structures of pointers and, either explicitly or implicitly, call functions through pointers."* C meets those requirements. MIDL has always supported generating C-compatible interface definitions. Direct2D is no exception.

Comment: @IInspectable, aggregate returns in methods like ID2D1Bitmap::GetSize() are special in a sense that midl will generate incompatible C prototype for it. Next issue is overloaded methods that won't work either. As you might have noticed SDK does not provide d2d/dwrite idls likely for that reason. Generic COM articles unfortunately won't fix that.

Comment: @bun Why would overloaded functions not work? Each overload has a unique index in the v-table. MIDL knows to append numeric suffixes to the ABI names in this case.

Comment: I don't know how you checked that, for it definitely doesn't do that. You can't have two methods of the same name, that's error "MIDL2003 redefinition". It does allow you to declare a method reusing name from interface it inherits from, but all that gets you is a C structure with two fields of the same name.

Comment: @bunglehead Turns out that Direct2D is indeed special, though it's not actually the interfaces that weren't C-friendly. There's no technical reason why Direct2D couldn't be used from C (it's COM, after all). The actual issue comes down to the Direct2D Team choosing non-standard tooling, ultimately forcing them to remove the C-style headers from the SDK. More info here: [The oracle always tells the truth, even when it is wrong: COM method calls with a user-defined type as a return value](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220113-00/?p=106152).

Comment: @IInspectable, although the question  is irrelevant for me for quite a long time, it would be great if your could answer to this question so that further readers of this question can easily find the answer!

Comment: @IInspectable, it doesn't matter what it's called, COM or not. None of the COM features are used for d2d/d3d components, except for IUknown inheritance, also inconsistently.  Custom tooling part comes from midl not expecting such prototypes. The point is that API design wasn't carefully evaluated, they could have used out pointers like everywhere else.